# Doubt regarding particle dynamics and hydrodynamics in Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, geodesics

The effective potential for particle orbits in the equatorial plane of a Schwarzschild black hole in units $G=M=c=1$ is given by $$V_{\textrm{eff}}=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{2}{r}\right)\left(1+\frac{l^2}{r^2}\right)} \qquad\qquad\qquad(1)$$

When we are interested in studying accretion flows in the equatorial plane of a Schwarzschild black hole, we need to analyze the relativistic hydrodynamic equations. If we consider radial accretion of matter (with no angular momentum) in the equatorial plane, the **relativistic Euler equation** can be written as [page-569 of Shapiro and Teukolsky with $M=1$ due to chosen convention]
$$uu'+\frac{1}{r^2}+\left(1-\frac{2}{r}+u^2\right)a^2\frac{n'}{n}=0$$
where $n$ is the baryon density and $u'=\dfrac{du}{dr}$.

From the above equation, we can easily identify the second term as the **gravitational force** experienced by the matter when the matter falls radially and there is no angular momentum.

I tried to derive similar results considering non-zero angular momentum and I found the equation
$$uu'+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{r^3-l^2(r-2)^2}{r^3-l^2(r-2)}+\left(1-\frac{2}{r}+u^2\right)a^2\frac{n'}{n}=0$$

From this equation, we observe that the **radial force** is of the form
$$f_r=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{r^3-l^2(r-2)^2}{r^3-l^2(r-2)} \qquad\qquad\qquad(2)$$
In the limit $l=0$, we obtain the form given in Shapiro and Teukolsky.

*I integrated Eqn.$(2)$ to obtain the effective potential suitable for studying fluid motion in the equatorial plane of a Schwarzschild black hole. I found that the potential nearly matches with $V_{\textrm{eff}}$ given by Eqn.$(1)$, but with a deviation (though negligible, but increases with $l$) close to the black hole.*

**However, I am curious about the following:**

> *The deviation is very negligible and we can easily use the effective potential obtained by integrating $f_r$. However, since both the expressions
>   are derived from the exact equations (one from relativistic particle
>   dynamics and the other from relativistic hydrodynamics), I think that
>   this deviation is due to the transition from particle
>   dynamics to hydrodynamics, incorporating which both the potentials
>   would match exactly. So my questions are:*
>
> 1. *Is the deviation really due to the use of two different approaches i.e., particle
>      dynamics and hydrodynamics?*
> 2. *If true, then is it possible to find a mathematical expression of this deviation from
>      General Relativity?*

N.B.: If related stuffs are already available in the literature, it would be very helpful if they are mentioned here.

Comment: (Other high rep users correct me if I'm wrong) I've removed the link to the book, as I believe on SE we don't allow links to pirated material.

Comment: I've added a question mark as otherwise this looks like a mere assertion.

Comment: @Richard How did you derive equation (2)?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Equation (2) can be derived from the radial Euler equation $(p+\rho)u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^r + (g^{\mu r}+u^\mu u^r)\partial_\mu p=0$ and using the Schwarzschild metric with the angular momentum defined by $l=\dfrac{\tilde{l}}{\mathscr{E}}=-\dfrac{hu_\phi}{hu_t}$, where $h$ is the enthalpy density. The angular momentum $\tilde{l}$ is conserved for particles and fluids, whereas $l$ is conserved only for fluids.

Comment: @Richard If there is $u_{\phi}\ne  0$, then how did you separate the equations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev We can write $u_\phi=-lu_t$ and then use the expression of $u_t$ for the Schwarzschild metric. So, $u_\phi$ is contained in $l$, i.e.,the specific angular momentum of the fluid.